# How to have multiple dialogs in a single fragment

Tags: sapui5

I have been working on dialog in fragment , for a sample :

### test.fragment.xml :

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Dialog title="P Selection" id='TestDialog1'>
      <content>
       <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormDisplay354"
            minWidth="1024"
            maxContainerCols="2"
            editable="false"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            title=""
            labelSpanL="3"
            labelSpanM="3"
            emptySpanL="4"
            emptySpanM="4"
            columnsL="1"
            columnsM="1">
            <f:content>
                <Label text="DC" />  
                <Select id='Test1DCId'
                    forceSelection="false"
                    items="{
                        path: '/P/DC',
                        sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                    }">
                    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{value}" />
                </Select>
                <Label text="Quantity" />
                <Select id='Test1Quantity'
                    forceSelection="false"
                    items="{
                        path: '/P/Quantity',
                        sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                    }">
                    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{value}" />
                </Select>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
      </content>
      <buttons>
        <Button text="OK" press="onTest1OkButtonPress" />
      </buttons>
          <buttons>
        <Button text="Cancel" press="onTest1CancelButtonPress" />
      </buttons>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

### In test.view.xml:

The view part when I want to open a dialog is as:

```
<m:Select id="Gu" items="{/Gu/GList}" change="onTestPress">
    <c:Item key="{key}" text="{value}" />
    <m:layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
    </m:layoutData>
</m:Select>
```

### In test.Controller.js:

```
  onTestPress: function () {
    this.ADD = 'Yes';
    if (!this.byId("TestDialog1")) {
      this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("test", this);
      this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog);
    }
    this._oDialog.open();
  },
```

here in similar way may I how can I use multiple dialogs in the same fragment ? Is this possible ?

I have tried as giving another dialog with different ID `TestDialog2` ,

And in view some test button and on press , i need to open a Dialog and i tried as:

```
  onTestButtonPress: function () {
    this.ADD = 'Yes';
    if (!this.byId("TestDialog2")) {
      this._oDialog1 = sap.ui.xmlfragment("test1", this);
      this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog1);
    }
    this._oDialog1.open();
  },
```

But this doesn't work as expected also Throws error `Error: Error: adding element with duplicate id.....`

I have searched Doc's and many examples but i have been stuck finding an example which shows this use case......

Any help or a sample or a guiding link is much appreciated , TIA

Comment: use afterClose event and destroy the dialog and check.

Comment: Sure I will...am I doing the correct way ?.....can you please show me a sample example on using multiple dialogs in a fragment

Comment: now i'm confused about your requirement. So, every time you open the fragment you should change the content inside the simple form, am I correct??

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean opening and closing the same dialog multiple times? You can either reuse the the dialog and just update the data inside or destroy it as santosh mentioned and create it freshly everytime.

Comment: sorry to be clear ....Is it possible to have multiple dialogs in a single fragment ? form is inside a `<dialog>` ........If so ,may i know how could i get the particular dialog in controller ?

Comment: @santhosh Not content inside form but a new dialog in fragment...say `<fragment> <dialog id='1'><form1></form1></dialog>  <dialog id='2'><form2></form2></dialog>  <dialog id='3'><form3></form3></dialog> </fragment>`......syntactically I may be doing this wrong but for what I'm actually trying is this..... hope it is clear

Comment: No, you cannot have multiple dialogs inside a fragment. What is the purpose of using multiple dialogs inside a fragment? Better to have multiple fragments and instantiate accordingly.

Comment: @santhosh to open a particular dialog with id when required....

Comment: Why does your Dialog (and your Select) have an ID in the first place? You can do almost everything without an ID

Comment: @Marc I have had an ID for select to set a particular value  , and for Dialog I have tried like with ID's i can get the respective Dialog ......is that possible to set the value to select without an ID ??....may know how this can be done ?.....Also is that possible to set dialog title based on a drop down selection as in view ?

Comment: To get the respective dialog use `this._oDialog` and `this._oDialog1`. To set particular values use a JSONModel and bind your dialogs to that model. Very minimal coding example: `o = new JSONModel({selKey: ""}); oDialog.setModel(o, "dialogModel");` and your view: `<Select selectedKey="{dialogModel>/selKey}" />`. To change the sel key, use `setProperty` on the dialog model (`this._oDialog.getModel("dialogModel").setProperty("/selKey", "newValue");`)

Comment: Thanks @Marc for the example....I would try that

Comment: @Marc may i know how to set the tilte of dialog based on `change` of `select` in view ?.....please give as an answer with a minimum example as above ....a view(with a select dropdown),a fragment with dialog's in it(if possible) ,a controller  ...

Comment: Again, use the JSONModel. In your `change` event create the string and set it to your model. The attribute `title` if your dialog should be bound to the new property in your dialog model. Will not provide code since you can figure this out on your own using my last comment.

Comment: @Marc Would you suggest any links apart from document to go through UI5 from basics ?

Comment: Well the walkthrough is great ofc, but some things are just experience: Models are your friend, IDs are your enemy.

Comment: IDs are enemies ?....why is that @Marc

Comment: IDs mean more dependencies. If you bind your view to a model you can change a single property and it automatically updates every control that is bound to that property. With IDs you have to get every single control via ID and update it manually (hopefully you don't forget a control). It's also more work to replace a control.

Comment: Makes sense....